# How to bind connection string to my SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I  have a connection string in my web.config and a gridview. below is code for how I configured my gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
```

....

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sb_cpdConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT colID, lname, fname, address, hobby from table1 where column like '%' ">
<SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="lname" PropertyName="Text" 
                Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="fname" PropertyName="Text" 
                Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Since I want to show another gridview from my child data source and I am now using code behind, how do I bind my SqlDataSource to my databasae as I did in my aspx code.

Below is how I have done so far.

```
private SqlDataSource ChildDataSource(string strCustometId, string strSort)
{
    string strQRY = "";
    SqlDataSource ds = new SqlDataSource();
    string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sb_cpdConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    myConnection.Open();
strQRY = "SELECT [ID], [QuizNo]," +
                            "[Status],[CertificateNo],[Received] FROM [cpd_certificates]" +
                            " WHERE [ID] = '" + strCustometId + "'" +
                            "HAVING COUNT(*)=0 " + strSort;
   // this is where I need help to bind connection string.
```

I get an error: The connectionString property has been initialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should assign the connection string to data source's connection string property

```
string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sb_cpdConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
ds.ConnectionString = connectionString;
```